# How to Call a Function inside a Render Class in React-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to call a function inside an imported render class. I tried the following but no success.

class1.js

```
import class2 from "./class2";
export default class1 MainCategoriesScreen extends React.PureComponent  {
    renderItem({ item }) {
       return <Class2 product={item}/>
    }

    changeCategoryId(id){
        console.log(id);
    }

    render() {
     return (
      <FlatList
      data={this.state.products}
      renderItem={this.renderItem}
      ...
```

}

and for class2

```
  render() {
   return (
      <Card style={{flex:1}}>
          <CardItem cardBody button
            onPress={this.changeCategoryId(product.id)}>
            ...
          </CardItem>
            ...
}
export default withNavigation(class2 );
```

Also I tried these:

```
this.changeCategoryId(product.id)
this.changeCategoryId(product.id)
this.changeCategoryId.bind(product.id)
this.props.changeCategoryId(product.id)
```

Comment: Did you try `onPress={() => this.changeCategoryId(item.id)}`

Comment: @tarzenchugh Yes. It can not find function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `changeCategoryId` method from class 1 to class 2 as a prop, and then call it like `this.props.changeCategoryId()`:

```
// class 1
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    ...

    this.renderItem = this.renderItem.bind(this);
    this.changeCategoryId = this.changeCategoryId.bind(this);
}

renderItem({ item }) {
   return <Class2 product={item}
                  changeCategoryId={this.changeCategoryId}/>
}

// class 2
  render() {
    return (
      <Card style={{flex:1}}>
        <CardItem cardBody button
          onPress={this.props.changeCategoryId(product.id)}>
          ...
        </CardItem>
      ...
```

Note that you need to bind both `changeCategoryId` and `renderItem` in class 1.

Comment: Yes. it is in class1. But I test your code. for `changeCategoryId={this.changeCategoryId.bind(this)}` I get this error: can not read property 'bind' of underfind

Comment: The renderItem method must be binded too, like `this.renderItem = this.renderItem.bind(this)` (I updated the answer with this). The other option is defining the methods with the arrow function syntax, as shown in Kape's answer, that does not need binding of any method (note that the method definition there is slightly different than your code). Either using bind or that other way of defining methods should work fine

Comment: Thanks. I must bind `renderItem`  too.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue, just do this:

```
export default class1 MainCategoriesScreen extends React.PureComponent  {
  renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return <Class2 product={item} onPress={this.myfunction} />
  }

  myfunction = (id) => {
      console.log(id);
  }

  render() {
    return (
     <FlatList
       data={this.state.products}
       renderItem={this.renderItem}
       ...
```

and

```
render() {
  return (
    <Card style={{flex:1}}>
      <CardItem cardBody button
        onPress={() => this.props.onPress(product.id)}>
        ...
      </CardItem>
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but for me do not works. `_this.props.onPress in not a function`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
renderItem = ({ item }) => {
   return <Class2 product={item} onPress={id => this.myfunction(id)} />
}

myfunction(id) {
  console.log(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
renderItem({ item }) {
  return <Class2 product={item}/>
}
```

You appear to be missing passing the prop into *Class2*, which will handle the changeCategoryId.

```
renderItem({ item }) {
  return <Class2 changeCategoryId={this.changeCategoryId} product={item}/>
}
```

This means, Class2 will now have access to a prop, called `changeCategoryId` which will be Class1's `changeCategoryId` function.

Then in the render function within your Class2, you can do:

```
<CardItem cardBody button
  onPress={() => this.props.changeCategoryId(product.id)}>
  ...
```